# pycco (markdown doc generator), how-to embed an js (knowl) anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, markdown

I am working with [pycco](http://fitzgen.github.io/pycco/), and would like to embed a [knowl](http://www.aimath.org/knowlepedia/), as part of the doc-html.

I am able to render doc-html directly if they are simply input as markdown comments.
ie `#<div>hi<div>` will correctly display in the doc-html.

I insert the javascript through the comments:

```
"""
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
</script> 
<link href="http://aimath.org/knowlstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://aimath.org/knowl.js"></script>
"""
```

However, when I insert a knowl anchor, `<a knowl="/knowl/k1.html">knwl1</a>`, the element opens/closes in the correct area; but, the contents of the linked html are not visible.

If I try styling the anchor (in some pycco-like manner) then the element spans the entire page and won't open or close in the right area.  The html content doesn't display either.

```
<td class=docs>
    <div class="octowrap">
      <a class="octothorpe" href="#section-7">#</a>
    </div>
    <a knowl="/knowl/k1.html">knowli.</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi, got it to work if linked files are not in sub-directories.  So how do you relative link subdirectories in markdown ?

Comment: Doesn't a leading slash usually mean that you have an absolute reference?  Shouldn't a subdirectory be `knowl='knowl/k1.html'`?